# What might be causing a kernel module to get corrupted?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I am sporadically getting a weird effect with my kernel module that I cannot quite place (this is on a Raspberry Pi4 using Raspberry OS, I am using an SSD - no SD card; 3A power supply).

I have built a kernel module that still seems to have some kind of bug that may
randomly crash the device (sometimes after 4 secs.. next time after 15 minutes, etc).

What puzzles me is this: I have a successfully built module that can load and run. At some point the device freezes (probably due to my module). I restart the device but when I try to again insert the same kernel module - the one that had been loaded successfully just before the reboot - I am now getting:

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module abc.ko: Invalid parameters

.. and I have to recompile the module (to which I have made absolutely no SW changes) before I am again able to insert it. Interestingly this effect does not occur every time the device freezes but only sometimes.. what is going on? Is there some mechanism in Linux that might "invalidate" some kernel module binary such that it can no longer be used?

PS: The only additional things connected to the Raspberry's 5V power supply are: the SSD (which draws between 80-100mA via USB3), a CPU fan (which supposedly is 200mA), and the PCB that hosts an audio chip used for my project (which draws 80mA).. i.e. I would think that the total 380mA should be well within the range of what my 3A power supply should be able to handle.

Comment: Have you verified there is no faulty hardware? It sounds like the SSD may have a fault that is causing data corruption--which may corrupt the filesystem further when it crashes without the kernel able to save any cached changes back to the SSD.

Comment: @C.M.why would the kernel make "cached changes" to my "kernel module" binary? should it not be a read only file conceptually? I just want to confirm that there is no scenario in which the kernel might deliberately make changes to the binary. if no such scenario exists then it probably is some kind of HW issue (probably not the SSD since it is already the 2nd SSD that I've observed this effect with..).

Comment: Without further detail, we cannot know if that is the case with any certainty, we can only make guesses. It does not need to change the binary itself, but any file system data structure that corrupts it, such as the inode pointers, might cause it to point to some random sector of the disk which it treats as invalid data. We also do not know what "abc.ko" is doing. It might be trying to modify itself, for example, and in the process it locks up, corrupting itself.

Comment: As far as the "read only" in general, not just with the module.. Again, it depends. Conceptually, yes, it should not need to modify anything during boot. But some modules may need to do just that to update state information. They might also do that _after_ boot, during runtime. And when it locks up and crashes, corruption can occur.

Comment: @C.M. I created a separate question that provides more info regarding the impl of my module (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646549/am-i-making-invalid-assumptions-with-regard-to-my-kernel-modules-shared-memory ),, I don't know if/how the two issues might be related

Comment: I posted a comment on that post, but _probably_ not related to this one... other than it reminded me of the problems I would have with cores 2 and 4 crashing because they are "fake cores" (but your other post is using core 3, so...) Let's try to troubleshoot the corruption issue further? Would you recompile the module, and afterwards, make an exact copy of it? My thinking here is to verify if the module is indeed being modified by doing a byte-by-byte comparison against the backup looking for changes. If it is not, then we can consider other possibilities.

Comment: I just had another instance of "file corruption".. this time it was my userland executable. When trying to recompile it, the compiler complained about some .o file being corrupt as well.. indeed all of my previously compiled .o files suddenly show file length of 0, i.e. the directory entries still seem to be there but the file data has "disappeared". I presume this is the same thing that had happend to my above kernel module. I would guess that whatever is manipulating those directory entries might actually be triggering the crash of the system (maybe due to being starved by my kernel module)

Comment: That suggests to me what my original thinking was... It may no be the file itself getting corrupted, but the file system data (directory structures and such). Most OSes cache this data internally since a read/write operations are thousands of times slower than the CPU. If something crashes before the OS sync's it's cache copy to disk, the disk data may become broken. Normally, the boot-time part of the filesystem are not modified, so there is no need to sync, so I though maybe a bad SSD. What happens if you force a `sync` at regular intervals, such as a cronjob?

Comment: (And a caveat: `sync`ing won't solve the problem, it would only be a workaround. You will sill need to find and fix the original problem!)